# Combine jqGrid toolbar search and custom search

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Is it possible to have jqGrid do a search based on a custom form, but then also allow further filtering of that dataset using the toolbar search?

I've already got a custom form set up, and it executes searches perfectly. I can easily implement the entire search experience in the advanced form, but I'm looking at combining the two.

**Update:** This is an existing project that uses Trirand's MVC helpers. LoadOnce and other settings mentioned in the comments are not explicitly set, so I can only assume that they are all set to the defaults.

The toolbar search is just the stock setup as far as I can tell.

I think the only prerequisite for a solution is that the existing MVC helper libraries stay in place in order to maintain consistency with the rest of the project.

**Update 2:** I should add that the custom form is just that, a custom HTML form. I have another problem with not being able to get the search results into the grid, and I've been trying to get Trirand support on that, but no luck so far.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The problem is that the implementation depends on *details*. Do you use *datatype: "local"* or `datatype: "json"` (or "xml") where the searching are **on the server side only**? Do you use probably `loadonce: true` and use searching *on the client side* with `datatype: "json"`? You wrote about "custom form". It's just visual part of the searching. How you save the searching parameters. Do you use `filters` part of `postData` or extend `postData` with other parameters? In any way **more details required** to answer on your question so that it could help you really.

Comment: Long story short, if you point me in the right direction, I'm not really locked into the current implementation except for using the MVC Helpers.